# Where should I start for Web Services with PHP with C# Client?

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I have been working in C# for a while ago, and recently started again with PHP; and I wonder if it is possible to make web services in php that can be consumed from C#.

Googling, i found various frameworks as NuSOAP, Zend and others.

My questions are:

- What good frameworks are out there for doing SOAP Web Services development with PHP?
- Where can I start from?
- How can I achieve Database agnosticism in PHP?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> What good frameworks are out there for doing SOAP Web Services development with PHP?

PHP now has [a native soap client and server library](http://www.php.net/soap). Don't use nusoap.

> Where can I start from?

[The manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php)

> How can I achieve Database agnosticism in PHP?

You can get database [connectivity abstraction through PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you publish a WSDL it's very easy to consume a web service from any client. With Visual Studio there is actually a generator that will read the WSDL and generate classes which help you access the web service on its own.

I haven't done it in a while but I am just letting you know it exists. Also, I have in the past wrote a SOAP web service in PHP and used a C# client to access it. So it is definitely possible.

I believe I used NuSOAP and it was quite simple because it actually auto-generated the WSDL by adding a ?wsdl at the end of the URL. I don't think NuSOAP is being developed anymore though but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is SOAP support in PHP since a while, and you can user nusoap too if you have to.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/
Nusoap may needs a little more work, but last time I've checked it supported a bit more bits and pieces of the standard.

It could have been changed since then.